# PDOException "column not found" but does exist

Tags: 7, ubercart, domain-access

This is on Drupal 7.39 with Domain Access and Ubercart

When pressing "checkout" button the site returns and error which shows in the dblog as:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'uc_payment_method_credit_checkout' in 'where clause': SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name =uc_payment_method_credit_checkout LIMIT 0, 1; Array ( ) in uc_domain_variable_get() (line 291 of /. . . /uc_domain.module).

Line 291 of the uc_domain_module is:

```
$result = db_query_range("SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name =" . $variable, 0, 1)->fetchField();
```

The column exists in the variable table and I triple checked it for an exact format match  (they all exist for the variable_set commands  I placed to be used in the install file)

This module is a Drupal 7 version module but is not an official project owned or maintained by anyone though it was originally written by the Drupal 6 project author and maintainer and released by him at https://www.drupal.org/node/946574.  I am working with that released file as modified by "henk" - but this section is unchanged by "henk" either

The equivalent command in the Drupal 6 version is near identical

**D6 version starts . . .**
  $result = db_result(db_query("SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name = '%s'", $variable));

**D6 version ends . . .**

I put a space in the => " . . . WHERE name = " . $variable . . ." to match the D6 version

But the error now simply reads  " . . .  WHERE name = uc_payment_method_credit_checkout . . . " with the space at "name = "

It seems to work -partly as it created an order entry in uc_domain_orders when i tries to test it - somehow - even though the jump to checkout failed.

This is not not like any other "column not found" issue I have searched here.

Anyone have any words of wisdom or ideas ???

Answer (score 2):

Concatenating variables into an SQL query is usually a bad idea (search for SQL injection and you'll see why). The D6 version you're starting with:

```
$result = db_result(db_query("SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name = '%s'", $variable));
```

uses parameters, you just need to convert that to use the newer query substitution in D7. The docs for [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) have some good examples, essentially what you need for this particular query is:

```
$query = 'SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name = :name';
$params = array(':name' => $variable);
$result = db_query($query, $params)->fetchField();
```

Comment: that's really accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you reported **exactly** both the error message and the code part, then the error is pretty "normal".

The D6 version
`"SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name = '%s'"`
includes simple quotes around `%s`, so the resulting query in the case you cited is
`SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name ='uc_payment_method_credit_checkout' LIMIT 0, 1`

At the opposite in your D7 modified version
`"SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name =" . $variable`
you didn't keep the quotes, so the resulting query becomes
`SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name =uc_payment_method_credit_checkout LIMIT 0, 1`
and without quotes SQL interprets `uc_payment_method_credit_checkout` as a column-name rather than a string.

This was only to explain why the error happens. In the other hand I totally agree with Clive recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

i am not the author of any of this code; but Clive gave me the clue - while the question was on hold as off topic - so I reformulated the query to

```
 $result = db_query_range("SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name = :name", 0, 1, array(':name' => $variable))->fetchField();
```

Of course Clive's version works equally as well